# Basis for the space $L[P^{-1}Q^{-1}]$ of functions on a Riemann surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

While reading about hyperelliptic Riemann surfaces from Farkas and Kra, I came across this line:

> Let $M$ be a hyperelliptic Riemann surface of genus $\geq 2 $. Choose a
> function $z$ of degree 2 on $M$ ... Let the polar divisor of $z$ be $P_1 Q_1$.

After this they've stated that $\{1,z\}$ forms a basis for $L[P_1^{-1} Q_1^{-1}]$ (the space of meromorphic functions which are multiples of $P_1^{-1} Q_1^{-1}$).

I don't understand why this must be true. Can't there be meromorphic functions with poles at $P_1$ and $Q_1$ but zeroes at places other than the zeroes of $z$?
Also , the Riemann-Roch theorem says that

$$\dim(L[P_1^{-1} Q_1^{-1}])=2-g+1+i[P_1Q_1].$$ So, there is no guarantee that the space in question will have dimension $2$ .

Can someone please help clear my doubts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We know $\ell(P_1)=\ell(0)=1$ (since $M$ is not $\mathbb{P}^1$) so $\ell(P_1+Q_1)\leq \ell(P_1)+1=2$.

Comment: How do you arrive at the above inequality?

Comment: For any divisor $D$, we have $\ell(D+P)\leq\ell(D)+1$.  Can you see why?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I wasn't familiar with that notation. $dim(L[P^{-1}Q^{-1}])-dim(L[P^{-1}])=1 +i[PQ]-i[P]$ and $i[PQ]-i[P] \leq 1$. Thanks a lot.